# Rails doesn't expand the variable "count" when displays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am developing a Rails 2.3.8 app and I stumbled upon a strange form error:
in all errors messages in any input forms, the variable count is not expanded.
As instance if I fill in the following form with a too long string (> 300 chars, I've set max=300), the form will display the message:
**"is too long (maximum is {{count}} characters)"** instead of:
**"is too long (maximum is 300 characters)"**

```
- form_for(@event) do |f|
  = f.label :description
  %br
  = f.text_area :description
  =  f.error_message_on :description
```

Do you have any ideas why this happens ?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmine had this issue and they fixed it in 1.0.5.

See here for the changes:

http://www.redmine.org/news/49

in the message they say something along these lines:

> Among 11 bug fixes, Redmine 1.0.5
>   solves the incompatibility with the
>   i18n 0.5.0 gem. The appropriate i18n
>   gem version (0.4.2) is now required

so i assume you need to install the 0.4.2 i18n gem :)

Comment: but I am already using i18n (0.5.0):
$ gem list | grep i18 return
"i18n (0.5.0)" Have I do a downgrade ?

Comment: gem install i18n -v=0.4.2 this wil install the proper version. you also need to request that version from your application. Alternatively try to see if %{key} syntax works. That way you can probably use the i18n 0.5+.

Comment: Look here http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/4516/entry/trunk/config/boot.rb at the end of the file how to request the proper version for your application.

Comment: I've unistalled the i18n 0.5 and installed the 0.42 (as you suggest me). Now it works :) Thank you

Comment: with 0.4.2 or with the %{} syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and installing i18n 0.4.2 solved it for me.